# Distinguish modeless vs modal dialog

Tags: mfc, dialog, modal-dialog

I want use the same class `CTestDialog` for a modal dialog

```
CTestDialog dlg;
dlg.DoModal();
```

and for a modeless Dialog

```
m_pDlg = new CTestDialog;
m_pDlg->Create(CTestDialog::IDD,this);
m_pDlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

The problem I have is at PostNcDestroy(..) it crashes if it is constructed as modal Dialog:

```
void CTestDialog::PostNcDestroy() 
{   
  CDialog::PostNcDestroy();
  delete this;                 // <= need for modeless, but Crash! if constructed as modal Dialog
}
```

How can I determine, in a straightforward way, if the class was constructed as modeless or modal dialog?

Comment: Yes I want avoid delete if the dialog is constructed as modal dialog (on the stack). 
Typically modeless dialog objects are created somewhere on the heap and destroyed itself in PostNcDestroy()

Comment: Have you tried checking for the [DS_MODALFRAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729172(v=vs.85).aspx) style?

Comment: You need to leave delete this; as is otherwise you will have memory leak

Comment: @rrirower  I have checked this, it has the same style, car I use the same class and the dialog ressource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the dialog's m_nModalResult. If it is -1 - the dialog was modeless; otherwise it will be one of IDOK, IDCANCEL, etc. codes.

[Edited to answer the comment]

This is different from the original question.
In the OK/Cancel handler, you can test:

```
if (m_nFlags & WF_MODALLOOP)
```

Comment: Almost, near to the solution. Yes m_nModalResult give the correct result in OnNcDestroy().
But I can not use this variable in OnOk() and OnCancel(). :(

    void CTestDialog::OnOK()
    {
  if (UpdateData(TRUE))
 {
  if (m_bModeless)
   DestroyWindow();
   DestroyWindow();
  else
   CDialogEx::OnOK();
 }
    }


    void CTestDialog::OnCancel()
    {
 if (m_bModeless)
  DestroyWindow();
 else
  CDialogEx::OnOK();
    }

Comment: Could you add the code of OnOK and OnCancel methods to your initial post?

Answer (score 1):

I have abandoned searching a solution if the MFC Dialog itself can distingish between modeless vs modal dialog.

This workaround works for me.
I have extended the constructor to tell if it is modeless or modal.

```
CTestDialog::CTestDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/, BOOL bModeless /*=false*/)
: CDialogEx(CTestDialog::IDD, pParent)
, m_bModeless(bModeless)
{
}

void CTestDialog::PostNcDestroy()
{
    CDialogEx::PostNcDestroy();
    if (m_bModeless)
        delete this;
}

void CTestDialog::OnOK()
{
    if (UpdateData(TRUE))
    {
    if (m_bModeless)
        DestroyWindow();
    else
        CDialogEx::OnOK();
    }

void CTestDialog::OnCancel()
{
    if (m_bModeless)
        DestroyWindow();
    else
        CDialogEx::OnOK();
}
```